# Python: writing list items to text files

Tags: python, excel, list, text-files, xlrd

I'm writing the content from one column in a rather large Excel file into separate text files using `xlrd`, one text file for each row in the column. In total, I have 1312 rows in the column, meaning I hope to get 1312 text files.

This should be trivial. I manage just fine to save all the individual Excel cells from the colum into a Python list of 1312 items. But for some reason when I run the code it only copies 619 out of 1312 list items into text files. I don't get an error message, the code compiles successfully, it just refuses to create the remaining files. It's also always 619 files that it creates, never more, never less.

Here is my code (The `date` is for naming the files after the date, which is another column in the Excel file. I made the `datelist` to check if it was perhaps not saving that part, but it is):

```
import xlrd
import os

path = r'C:\Users\data'
file = "data.xlsx"

os.chdir(path)

book = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
contentlist=[]
datelist=[]
for row in sheet.get_rows():
    date = str(row[5].value)
    datelist.append(date)
    content = str(row[7].value)
    contentlist.append(content)

    for item in datelist:
        filename = item + ".txt"
    for item in contentlist:
        with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(str(item))
```

Comment: The way your `for` loops are indented seems off, currently it looks like you change filename to every possible `item + '.txt'` then go writing, so you iterate through all your filenames, then only write, the last? one you created ?

Comment: also if to debug check the length of datelist and you can make a separate `set(datelist)` and also check it's length to make sure there's no duplicate values

Answer (score 0):

That code just looks completely wrong.

I guess what you mean is:

```
for row in sheet.get_rows():
    name, content = str(row[5].value), str(row[7].value)
    with open(name + ".txt", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(content)
```